# Why does Console.Out.WriteLine exist?

Tags: c#, .net, windows, console-application, reflector

Actually the question should be why does `Console.WriteLine` exist just to be a wrapper for `Console.Out.WriteLine`

I found this little method using intellisense, then opened [.NET reflector](http://www.red-gate.com/products/reflector/) and 'decompiled' the code for the `Console.WriteLine` method and found this:

```
public static void WriteLine(string value)
{
    Out.WriteLine(value);
}
```

So why is `WriteLine` implemented this way? Is it totally just a shortcut or is there another reason?

Answer (score 66, accepted):

`Console.WriteLine` is a static method. `Console.Out` is a static object that can get passed as a parameter to any method that takes a `TextWriter`, and that method could call the non-static member method `WriteLine`.

An example where this would be useful is some sort of customizable logging routines, where you might want to send the output to `stdout` (`Console.Out`), `stderr` (`Console.Error`) or nowhere (`System.IO.TextWriter.Null`), or anything else based on some runtime condition.

Answer (score 24):

**Brad Abrams** (The founding member of both CLR and .NET framework at Microsoft) says the following.

*Console.WriteLine() is simply a shortcut for Console.Out.WriteLine*. 
*Console was overloaded by WriteLine propery to make that much easier to write*.

Source: Book "The C# Programming Language by Anders Hejlsberg".